Convert well-known text or well-known binary into an ArcGIS Polygon
I have a geometry object in a database and I would like to render it on the front end using the ArcGIS JavaScript SDK.
var srid = 4326;           // or any other spatial reference
var wkt = 'POLYGON (...)'; // or wkb equivalent
var rings = ''             // <--- Conversion step I would like to make
const polygon = new Polygon({
    rings: rings,
    spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});

Right now, I pass in well-known binary and well-known text. On the plus side, the code doesn't error out. On the negative side, the polygon doesn't appear on the map. Instead, I just get a blank map.

Edit: I solved it using terraformer-wkt-parser.
import wkt from 'terraformer-wkt-parser';
...
const geom: GeoJSON.Polygon = wkt.parse(geometryString) as GeoJSON.Polygon;
const coordinates = geom.coordinates.flat() as any;
const polygon = new Polygon({
    rings: coordinates,
    spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
});


Seems like you already found a solution with terraformer-wkt-parser. However, terraformer-wkt-parser is deprecated and if possible, maybe consider using @terraformer/wkt instead:
// import { wktToGeoJSON } from 'https://esm.sh/@terraformer/wkt';
// import { Polygon } from 'https://esm.sh/@arcgis/core@4.29.10/geometry';

const srid = 4326;
const wkt = 'POLYGON((8.504 47.362, 8.508 47.363, 8.511 47.361, 8.504 47.362))'; 

const geojson = wktToGeoJSON(wkt);

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: geojson.coordinates,
  spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});


I recently came across with the JSTS library which would be an alternative:
// import { 
//     WKTReader,
//     GeoJSONWriter,
// } from 'https://esm.sh/jsts@2.11.3/org/locationtech/jts/io';
// import { Polygon } from 'https://esm.sh/@arcgis/core@4.29.10/geometry';

const srid = 4326;
const wkt = 'POLYGON((8.504 47.362, 8.508 47.363, 8.511 47.361, 8.504 47.362))'; 

const geometry = new WKTReader().read(wkt);

const geojson = new GeoJSONWriter().write(geometry);

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: geojson.coordinates,
  spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});


Addendum: There are other libraries such as wkt, wicket and wellknown. I just compile them here and hope it helps you and others to get an overview of libraries that parse a WKT string...
Let's start with wkt:
// import { parse } from 'https://esm.sh/wkt';
// import { Polygon } from 'https://esm.sh/@arcgis/core@4.29.10/geometry';

const srid = 4326;
const wkt = 'POLYGON((8.504 47.362, 8.508 47.363, 8.511 47.361, 8.504 47.362))'; 

const geojson = parse(wkt);

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: geojson.coordinates,
  spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});

Here is an example using wicket:
// import Wkt from 'https://esm.sh/wicket';
// import { Polygon } from 'https://esm.sh/@arcgis/core@4.29.10/geometry';

const srid = 4326;
const wktStr = 'POLYGON((8.504 47.362, 8.508 47.363, 8.511 47.361, 8.504 47.362))'; 

const geometry = new Wkt.Wkt().read(wktStr);

const geojson = geometry.toJson();

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: geojson.coordinates,
  spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});

And finally an example with wellknown:
// import wellknown from 'https://esm.sh/wellknown';
// import { Polygon } from 'https://esm.sh/@arcgis/core@4.29.10/geometry';

const srid = 4326;
const wkt = 'POLYGON((8.504 47.362, 8.508 47.363, 8.511 47.361, 8.504 47.362))'; 

const geojson = wellknown.parse(wkt);

const polygon = new Polygon({
  rings: geojson.coordinates,
  spatialReference: { wkid: srid },
});

